# How IntentService stops automatically while Service needs an stopService() call to stop it?

Tags: android, android-service

How is it that an IntentService stops automatically, while a normal Service needs a stopService() call to stop it? How does this work internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntentService calls stopSelf() when no more work (Intents) are in the queue to be processed. Just check IntentService.java source on a site like androidxref.com to see it:

http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java

To be more precise (check line 66 on the provided link): it doesn't actually test the queue, but calls stopSelf(int) every time. stopSelf() version that takes a startid(int) as parameter actually checks if the there are no newer start commands received by the service that still have to be handled. Because the IntentService only has one worker thread that processes intents sequentially, this test is the same as testing if the "queue is empty".

Comment: stopSelf()  means service stope it self

Comment: I know what stopSelf() does.. That is not the question that is asked (or, at least not entirely): what is more important (and also asked) is WHEN an IntentService decides to stop itself. You shouldn't have to call stopService() or stopSelf() on an IntentService yourself; it is covered.

Answer (score -2):

A service is a component which runs in the background, without direct interaction with the user. The Android platform provides and runs predefined system services and every Android application can use them, given the right permissions. and you can stop with following way.

```
Boolean stop1month = context.stopService(new Intent(context,Service.class));
or 
stopSelf()
```

in service class for mor information [see](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: Not only does the documentation of IntentService.onHandleIntent() explicitly state that calling stopService() on an IntentService is not needed or advised, you don't even answer the question. The question is how IntentService stop automatically, not how you stop a normal service.